# Update EventSourceArn through AWS CLI

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am very new to AWS and AWS CLI. I am trying to update the EventSourceArn of a lambda function through AWS CLI. Following is the command:

```
aws lambda update-event-source-mapping --uuid 31x113a3-5ac3-1234-1a1b-1232434df --EventSourceArn "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:232427:table/test/stream/2020-03-1122:02:20.112"
```

Following is the error I am getting while running this command from CLI:

> Unknown options: --EventSourceArn,
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:232427:table/test/stream/2020-03-1122:02:20.112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is no `--EventSourceArn` parameter for `aws lambda update-event-source-mapping`. Please [look at the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-event-source-mapping.html).

It appears you can only specify the event source ARN when you create a mapping. So you will probably need to [delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/delete-event-source-mapping.html) and then [create a new mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html) if you want to update the source.